# Zend framework view issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

So, running the newest ubuntu server and im having problems getting the view to work correctly in my application.

It seems that every "$this->view->variable" isnt working. My pages are all white with no html (i know it works on other servers as i have the same code running in a lot of places).

Comment: Retagged: -ubuntu10-4: Almost definitely not related to Ubuntu 10.4. -php5.3: Most certainly nothing to do w/ PHP 5.3 as opposed to php 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my index controller acting as the error controller and on this install (of php and ubuntu) it failed to work. I know the code i had worked because it is currently running on half a dozen other sites on different servers

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP error_log.  Your app is more than likely crashing and you just don't realize it.